# Run Perl code into GUI

Tags: perl, user-interface

I have been working in a Perl script to read log files, but none of the people at work 
want to use it as it requires run it from CLI, Im looking to integrate my Perl code which mainly
reads a txt file and produces and output (Already more than 2,000 lines) into a GUI which can be used with Windows or MAC PCs,
Example:
my perl script:

```
#./perl -i myfile
# HELLO this is the output!
```

Instead I want users to run the App and give them the chance to upload file and a Run button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then you can either write a [web based frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384744/how-do-i-make-an-ajax-request-to-perl-script-using-jquery-blur-event/7385851#7385851) or use a GUI library such as [Tk](https://metacpan.org/module/Tk), [Wx](https://metacpan.org/module/Wx) or [Gtk](https://metacpan.org/module/Gtk).

Answer (score 2):

Run as a CGI script which should ouput as HTML. For more you use template system like [Template tool kit](http://template-toolkit.org/)

Comment: Not necessary CGI - computer may not have a web server installed, so it may be easier to run a Perl-based webserver.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Tk is the most cross-platform GUI framework for Perl. It is very primitive (both in looks and API), but it works as expected almost everywhere with minimal fuss. Even with Gtk, I found there were some combinations of platforms and Perl deployments that just wouldn't work.

If you want to go the CGI route, try POEx::HTTP::Server. This will run a small web server within Perl without needing all the configuration of a full web server like Apache.